# How to print foreach loop results in textbox

Tags: c#

hi i am new to C# windows form applications

I need to print foreach loop details in textbox one by one.

I tried this code but it is getting errors...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] sss = textBox1.Text.Split(',');

    textBox2.Text="";

    foreach (string item in sss)
    {
        textBox2.Text.show("www.ebay.com/itm/" + item + Environment.NewLine + "WAIT SECONDS=1" + Environment.NewLine + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:watchLabel" + Environment.NewLine + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Watch" + Environment.NewLine + "WAIT SECONDS=1");
    }
}
```

please anyone fix the value and present the correct way of printing these results in textbox? or do you have suggestion plz tell me

Comment: Well? Care to tell us, which errors you are getting?

Comment: This is a **multiline** textbox, right?

Comment: yes.it is .And the problem was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not 100% sure that what you're trying to do is really what you want, but this will compile and put the text in the box:

```
foreach (string item in sss)
{
    textBox2.Text += 
        "www.ebay.com/itm/" + item + Environment.NewLine 
        + "WAIT SECONDS=1" + Environment.NewLine 
        + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:watchLabel" + Environment.NewLine 
        + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Watch" + Environment.NewLine 
        + "WAIT SECONDS=1";
}
```

`+=` works for strings or for numbers. It adds the right-hand value to the variable on the left. Here's a much simpler example:

```
int x = 10;
String s = "Barney";

x += 2;

s += " ";
s += "Rubble";

Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
12
Barney Rubble
```

`x += 2` is the same as `x = x + 2`, but easier to type.

Comment: thanks. your code is working. but i don't know what does +=  ?

Comment: @user3398379 += means "Take the thing on the left, and add the thing on the right to it".